# Read / Write very big pptx files with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We are using Apache POI (Version 3.9) in our project to create PowerPoint (pptx) files. However, some of them become really big (2000+ Slides with a lot of shapes on each slide), so that the generation yields `GC overhead limit exceeded` errors.

The heap space size is not in our control, as we only develop a plugin for an RCP 'parent' application.

Is there any way to write (and read) such big files? We use the streaming API for Excel Documents with big success, yet there is no streaming API for pptx.

My first idea was to split the big file (on creation) into smaller chunks which works. However, it is not possible to merge those files to one big file (getting GC errors again as POI now reads the big file)

I googled a lot for a good solution without success; unfortunally, pptx Support is only in a Beta state in POI at the moment.

Anyone has a suggestion here?

---

**My solution:**
Sadly I was not able to find a solution where I don't have to do a lot of xml editing. For all with the same problem, a small road map to merge the content of B into the presentation A

- unpack A and B into seperate folders
- get the last slide id from A, rename all slides from B so there is no name conflict
- add the new slides to `Content_Types.xml` and `presentations.xml`
- add the new entries in `presentations.xml`to `presentations.xml.rels`
- edit the `slideX.xml.rels` so that they reference the correct stuff

Basically make sure to copy all files with user generated content (slides, notes, layouts) into A, and rename it to avoid conflicts. Then search all `*.xml.rels` + `presentation.xml` + `content_types.xml` and add / modify the rId contents

Comment: 3.9 is rather old, what happens if you upgrade to the latest version? (3.14 as of writing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to do the merging of the separate slides outside of POI with the following:

- Look how the slides in a .pptx are stored (the .pptx is actually a Zip-file than can be unpacked and looked at)
- In the Merge-Code try to create a new zip-file with all the slides and any other adjustment that is necessary, usually the slides need to be listed in some relationship-file

Comment: Yeah, this might be a possiblity, although I hope to find a  solution which is not so 'low level'